Divs shifting down for no reason?
I tried to replicated a time table from my school, but my divs are shifting down and can't find any reason why. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with text or not having any space, because it's set to inline-flow.
Link to pen: https://codepen.io/BestCactus/pen/rNgMWGK


:root {
  --background-color: #242424;
  --card-color: #666665;
}

body {
  font-family: "Radio Canada Big", sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}

#card {
  background-color: var(--card-color);
  width: 80%;
  height: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 12px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#card * {
  color: white;
}

#table {
  height: 88%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: left;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.divOfWeek {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#mainHeading {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#headingDiv {
  height: 12%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.subject {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  text-align: center;
}

.articleTable {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  vertical-align: top; <--
}

.subInformation {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.subName {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#hiddenSubject {
  visibility: hidden;
}
<body>
    <div id="card">
      <div id="headingDiv">
        <h1 id="mainHeading">Rozvrh 1.A</h1>
      </div>
      <section id="table">
        <div class="divOfWeek">
          <h2 class="dOfWeek">PO</h2>
          <h2 class="dOfWeek">ÚT</h2>
          <h2 class="dOfWeek">ST</h2>
          <h2 class="dOfWeek">ČT</h2>
          <h2 class="dOfWeek">PÁ</h2>
        </div>
        <article class="articleTable">
          <div class="subject">
            <p class="subName">Fy</p>
            <p class="subInformation"><em>MIJ - </em><strong>407</strong></p>
          </div>
          <div class="subject">
            <p class="subName">M</p>
            <p class="subInformation"><em>Re - </em><strong>404</strong></p>
          </div>
          <div class="subject">
            <p class="subName">Z</p>
            <p class="subInformation"><em>Re - </em><strong>204</strong></p>
          </div>
          <div class="subject">
            <p class="subName">Nj</p>
            <p class="subInformation"><em>MOJ - </em><strong>316</strong></p>
          </div>
          <div class="subject">
            <p class="subName">Aj</p>
            <p class="subInformation"><em>LL - </em><strong>308</strong></p>
          </div>
          <div class="subject">
            <p class="subName">ZSV</p>
            <p class="subInformation"><em>VkD - </em><strong>204</strong></p>
          </div>
          <div id="hiddenSubject"class="subject">
            <p class="subName"></p>
            <p class="subInformation"><em><em><strong></strong></p>
          </div>
          <div class="subject">
            <p>EV</p>
          </div>
          <div class="subject">
            <p>EV</p>
          </div>
        </article>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



I tried the vertical-align: top; but that's not going to solve anything as the text doesn't change the shifting. I guess it could be something with the padding or margins but no idea what... I'm probably just super dumb and someone asked this already like 1000x times so I'm sorry...

I'm not sure how you want your time table to look like, but you have an unclosed <em> in your code inside your hiddenSubject div and everything seemed aligned once I fixed it. If that's not what you're looking for, please provide an image or an example of what you want your table to look like.

@Code_Dummy00 Oh, that's a dumb mistake, thank's bro, now everything works :)
